# building audit trail functionality

Tags: postgresql, scala, akka, cqrs, akka-persistence

Following is a use case in a workflow system

- Work order enters into a system. Work order will have a target which goes through different workflow states before completing a work order.
- Say Work order for a target Vehicle came into a system - workflow for this work oder involves 2 tasks say

  a)wash vehicle

  b)inspect vehicle

Say wash vehicle workflow task changes vehicle attribute from "not washed" to "washed". And say "inspect vehicle" workflow task changes vehicle attribute "not inspected" to "inspection done"

If user is pulling work order data user will always see latest vehicle data (in this example assuming both workflow tasks are completed user will see value "washed" and "inspection done". However when user pulls ONLY workflow Task Wash Vehicle data -> user will see "washed" -Though second task was done, workflow Task 1 will only see that that it modified. Getting data for Workflow Task 2 will see both "washed" and "inspection done"

This involves milstoning (audit trail) of data; One approach is as shown below image - where when workflow task modifies data it'll update version number, modified_ts and maintain that version number in it's own data row (via a JOIN table as depicted below). Basically this is nothing but maintaining a reference to a history record for workflow task data so when pulling workflow task data it knows which history record to pull back. please ignore `parent_id` and other notes, noise in a below picture. it's not relevant for this question.

[image]

I am thinking event sourcing will also be another alternative design - however don't want to apply event sourcing(or any other similar solution) as a whole sale solution but only for this particular use case (affecting only 3 or so tables where audit trail matters). I am trying to evaluate if CQRS/Event sourcing is a right fit as a partial solution (again only limited to 3-4 tables which need to preserve history/audit trail data) or ES/CQRS will be an overkill? any other thoughts?

P.S. Though this isn't related to Scala - Scala is a platform we are using hence tagging it to see if there are language specific solutions that can help. tagging Akka for finding out if ES/CQRS via Akka persistence is an option or not. Postgresql is a db - And DB triggers is not a solution I am looking for.